# Using CC BY-NC-ND images on website with ads

Tags: attribution, commercial, non-commercial, cc-by-nc-nd

I am currently developing an online service that allows to share and download music from different source on the internet, this is a free service without subscription or registration, I found a perfect flag icons I will like to integrate into the website countries section, but it comes with Creative Commons license: [Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/).

I'm seriously confused on whether to use the flags because I am going to be running advertisements from Google and some other places to help with the financing of the web hosting and the Terms are:

**You must give appropriate credit**

- I really don't want to attribute any link on that page that has the logo

**You may not use the material for commercial purposes.**

- Does running of advert which might earn me some cash means I can't use it?

Comment: This doesn't address ads in particular, but there's a great write-up of the problems with NC here: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1246/50

Comment: If you really don't want to give attribution to the original author whose work you're using, then the entire Creative Commons family of licenses is definitely not for you (except CC0). If it makes it easier, possibly you could link to a credits/about page with the attribution; I'm not sure.

Comment: If the license requests attribution, you have to attribute or refrain from using the images.

Comment: I haven't read this, but it may help? https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Defining_Noncommercial

Answer (score 4):

> A commercial use is one primarily intended for commercial advantage or monetary compensation. (Source: Creative commons)

So if you only have the adverts for financing the page it's ok, but when you are making money out of it it's not ok.

> I really don't want to attribute any link on that page that has the logo

That isn't possible. But you could contact the author of the images to give it to you under a special license.

But you could link to it under copyright or tos as written in the cc wiki:

> Author if supplied and attribution parties if designated in copyright notice, TOS, or other reasonable means

Comment: *give it to you under a special licence*, but in many parts of the world, attribution is a moral right, and is something that can't be revoked, even by the author itself.

Comment: @Zizouz212 but one doesn't know, so one could try

Comment: Wait what? I'm confused.

Comment: @Zizouz212 maybe the author lives somewhere where he can grant you that right

Comment: hi, what if i can give the attribution inside the about us page, will that be fine?

Comment: @femotizo yes that's possible

Comment: For a bit of discussion what "commercial use" is , see: https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/NonCommercial_interpretation